# Longest substring without repeating characters in python

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a pretty standard interview question. Find the longest substring without repeating characters. Here are the test cases,

```
abcabcbb -> 3
bbbbb -> 1
pwwkew -> 3
bpfbhmipx -> 7
tmmzuxt -> 5
```

Here's my code which uses a pretty simple approach with 2 pointers.

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    checklist = {}
    starting_index_of_current_substring = 0
    length_of_longest_substring = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(s):
        if v in checklist:
            starting_index_of_current_substring = checklist[v] + 1
        else:
            length_of_current_substring = i - starting_index_of_current_substring + 1
            length_of_longest_substring = max(length_of_current_substring, length_of_longest_substring)

        checklist[v] = i
    return length_of_longest_substring
```

My code passes all the test cases except the last one (actual 4, expected 5). Can someone help me modify the code to take care of the last test case. I don't wish to reinvent the algorithm.

Comment: When you jump the starting pointer ahead, you don't fix `checklist` to account for the characters no longer in the substring.

Comment: Downvoters, can you explain why ? There is a problem to answer to this question ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus: If you're talking about the downvotes on the now-deleted answers, both of them were wrong. Yours was wrong because you were merely counting distinct characters, rather than finding the length of the longest substring with only distinct characters. (Perhaps you had non-contiguous subsequences in mind, rather than substrings.)

Comment: If you're talking about downvotes on the question, I don't see any downvotes on the question. If there were any, they have been removed since you last looked.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm talking about the downvotes of the answers. i understand now. it's a language problem. i really don't know what `substring` mean. i thought the idea was counting only distinct characters.

Comment: @ChihebNexus a substring is a contiguous section of a string. `"foo"` is a substring of `"foobar"` (the substring represented by slicing `"foobar"[:3]`

Comment: Yes! Thanks i got it @AdamSmith

Comment: Just for fun, I worked this up in haskell [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1664077)

Comment: @Melissa - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is pretty old, but I think my solution fixes the bug in the original code.

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    checklist = {}
    starting_index_of_current_substring = 0
    length_of_longest_substring = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(s):
        if v in checklist:
          if checklist[v] >= starting_index_of_current_substring:
                        starting_index_of_current_substring = checklist[v] + 1

        length_of_current_substring = i - starting_index_of_current_substring + 1
        length_of_longest_substring = max(length_of_current_substring, length_of_longest_substring)
                checklist[v] = i
     return length_of_longest_substring
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple tweak in your code with 2 pointers to find the longest sub-string without repeating characters.

Change in your code is instead of calculating the length of longest substring when v is not present in checklist, I am calculating length of longest substring for all cases.

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    checklist = {}
    starting_index_of_current_substring = 0
    length_of_longest_substring = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(s):
        if v in checklist:
            starting_index_of_current_substring = max(starting_index_of_current_substring, checklist[v] + 1)
        checklist[v] = i
        length_of_longest_substring = max(length_of_longest_substring, i - starting_index_of_current_substring + 1)
    return length_of_longest_substring

## Main
result = {}
for string in ['abcabcbb', 'bbbbb', 'ppwwkew', 'wcabcdeghi', 'bpfbhmipx', 'tmmzuxt', 'AABGAKGIMN', 'stackoverflow']:
    result[string] = lengthOfLongestSubstring(string)
print(result)
```

Sample run:

```
{'abcabcbb': 3, 'bbbbb': 1, 'ppwwkew': 3, 'wcabcdeghi': 8, 'bpfbhmipx': 7, 'tmmzuxt': 5, 'AABGAKGIMN': 6, 'stackoverflow': 11}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt really iterate upon your solution, but it's a bit simpler approach, just to give you an idea how it could be also solved.

```
def longest_substr(s):
    longest = 0
    for start_index in range(len(s)):
        contains = set()
        for letter in s[start_index:]:
            if letter in contains:
                break
            contains.add(letter)
        longest = max(longest, len(contains))
    return longest
```

Comment: If you're ignoring the value you get from `enumerate`, you should probably just be looping on `range(len(s))` instead.

Comment: This solution is O(n2), mine is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Time and Space Management Optimised:

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
    curlen = maxlen = 0 # curlen saves the max len of substrings ending with current num
    for i, num in enumerate(s):
        curlen -= s[i-curlen:i].find(num)
        maxlen = max(maxlen, curlen)
    return maxlen
```

Answer (score 0):

## Find Longest Substring in the string without repeating characters.

````
def find_non_repeating_substring(input_str):
    output_length = 0
    longest_sub_str = ''
    len_str = len(input_str)
    index = 0
    while len_str != 1:
        l_str = ''
        for i in range(index, len(input_str)):
            if input_str[i] not in l_str:
                l_str = l_str + input_str[i]
            else:
                break
        
        sub_str_length = len(l_str)
        if sub_str_length >  output_length:
            output_length = sub_str_length
            longest_sub_str = l_str
        len_str = len_str -1
        index = index + 1
    return output_length,longest_sub_str
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_str = raw_input("Please enter the string: ")
    sub_str_length, sub_str = find_non_repeating_substring(input_str)
    print ('Longest Substing lenght is "{0}" and the sub string is "{1}"'.format(sub_str_length, sub_str))```
````

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
  def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
    x = []
    k = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c not in x:
            x.append(c)
        else:            
            x=[c]
        l = len(x)
        k = k if k > l else l 
    return k

o=Solution()
print(o.lengthOfLongestSubstring('abcabcdf'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I came up with an idiomatic way to do this with sets in Python:

```
        (lambda whole_str: [                                                                                                                                               
        "".join(whole_str[0:index])                                                                                                                                    
            for index in range(len(whole_str)) if sorted(set(sorted(                                                                                                       
                "".join(whole_str[:index]).replace(" ", "")))) == sorted(                                                                                              
                    "".join(whole_str[:index]).replace(" ", ""))])(                                                                                                    
                        "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog").pop()
```

This will give you:

```
Out[1]: 'the quick brown f'
```

If you don't want to use the lambda closure this will accomplish the same thing:

```
        ["".join("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"[0:index])                                                                                                  
           for index in range(len("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")) if sorted(set(sorted(                                                                     
             "".join("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"[:index]).replace(" ", "")))) == sorted(                                                            
                 "".join("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"[:index]).replace(" ", ""))].pop()
```

Comment: I almost mentioned if you want to count spaces as characters, you just need to drop the .replace(" ", "")